# How to catch the two digits number that is found bdfore a specific character combination?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have the following, table like, text which is taken from a Telnet socket.

```
-> iosFdShow 
 fd name                                     drv
  3 /tyCo/0                                    1 in out err
  4 (socket)                                   7   
  5 (socket)                                   7   
  6 (socket)                                   7   
  7 (socket)                                   7   
  8 (socket)                                   7   
  9 (socket)                                   7   
 10 (socket)                                   7   
 11 logfile                                    2   
 12 /doc0/Log/log.txt                          3   
 13 /doc0/CONFIG_A/System                      3   
 14 /doc0/CONFIG_A/Entity                      3   
 15 /doc0/CONFIG_A/Network                     3   
 16 /doc0/SW_B/fpga.rbf                        3   
 17 (socket)                                   7   
 18 (socket)                                   7   
 19 /tyCo/1                                    1   
 20 (socket)                                   7   
 21 (socket)                                   7   
 22 (socket)                                   7   
 23 (socket)                                   7   
 24 (socket)                                   7   
 25 (socket)                                   7   
 26 (socket)                                   7   
 27 (socket)                                   7   
 30 (dev deleted)tLogin3fedc10               n/a   
 31 (socket)                                   7   
 34 (dev deleted)tLogin4238110               n/a   
 35 (dev deleted)tShellRem73924472           n/a   
 36 (dev deleted)tLogin4238110               n/a   
 39 (dev deleted)tShellRem73924472           n/a   
 40 (dev deleted)tLogin4436b28               n/a   
 41 (dev deleted),)ְ,)׀,)א                n/a   
 42 (dev deleted)tShellRem71667576           n/a   
 43 (dev deleted)tLogin4238110               n/a   
 44 (dev deleted)   S0®ָכr                n/a   
 45 (dev deleted)tLogin4238110               n/a   
 46 (dev deleted)tLogin4355560               n/a   
 47 (dev deleted)tShellRem73924472           n/a   
 48 (dev deleted)tShellRem73924472           n/a   
 49 (dev deleted)tLogin4355560               n/a   
 50 (dev deleted)tLogin4355560               n/a   
 51 (dev deleted)tShellRem73924472           n/a   
 52 (dev deleted)tShellRem73924472           n/a   
 53 (dev deleted)tShellRem73924472           n/a   
 54 (dev deleted)tLogin4355560               n/a   
 55 (dev deleted)tLogin4355560               n/a   
 56 (dev deleted)                            n/a   
 57 (dev deleted)tLogin4355560               n/a   
 58 (dev deleted)tLogin4355560               n/a   
 59 (dev deleted)tLogin4355560               n/a   
 60 (dev deleted)tLogin4355560               n/a   
 61 (dev deleted)tLogin4355560               n/a   
 62 (dev deleted)ַ@e
Jh                n/a   
 63 (dev deleted)tLogin4355560               n/a   
 64 (dev deleted)tLogin4355560               n/a   
 65 (dev deleted)tLogin4355560               n/a   
 66 (dev deleted)כ8                        n/a   
 67 (dev deleted)   S0®ָכr                n/a   
 68 (dev deleted)                            n/a   
 69 (dev deleted)                            n/a   
 70 (dev deleted)                            n/a   
 71 (dev deleted)                            n/a   
 72 (dev deleted)tLogin4355560               n/a   
 73 (dev deleted)tLogin4355560               n/a   
 74 (dev deleted)tLogin4355560               n/a   
 75 (dev deleted)tLogin4355560               n/a   
 76 (dev deleted)tLogin4355560               n/a   
 77 (dev deleted)   S0®ָכr                n/a   
 78 (dev deleted)   S0®ָכr                n/a   
 79 (dev deleted)tLogin4238110               n/a   
 80 (dev deleted)   S0®ָכr                n/a   
 81 (dev deleted)tShellRem77561720           n/a   
 82 (dev deleted)tLogin4355560               n/a   
 83 (dev deleted)tLogin4355560               n/a   
 84 (dev deleted)tShellRem77561720           n/a   
 85 (dev deleted)tShellRem77561720           n/a   
 86 (dev deleted)tLogin4355560               n/a   
 87 (dev deleted)6  ¨2Lץָe               n/a   
 88 (dev deleted)״
ך`‎ןְ                n/a   
 89 (dev deleted)6  ¨2Lץָe               n/a   
 90 (dev deleted)ַ@e
Jh                n/a   
 91 (dev deleted)tShellRem77561720           n/a   
 92 (dev deleted)6  ¨2Lץָe               n/a   
 93 (dev deleted)ַ@e
Jh                n/a   
 94 (dev deleted)                            n/a   
 95 (dev deleted)ַ@e
Jh                n/a   
 96 (dev deleted)                            n/a   
 97 (dev deleted)״
ך`‎ןְ                n/a   
 98 (dev deleted)                            n/a   
 99 (dev deleted)״
ך`‎ןְ                n/a   
value = 100 = 0x64 = 'd'
->
```

I know that after I enter the 'iosFdShow' command I will get a table like result that ends up with the line (string) "value = 100 = 0x64 = 'd' ". What I don't know is the number of rows in this table and if this table will include other lines (debug lines from my box).

How can I catch the index of the last line ? in this case the index is 99

**EDIT:**

I found out that the following case (with two numbers at the last line make it harder to catch the index)

```
-> iosFdShow
 fd name                                     drv
  3 /tyCo/0                                    1 in out err
  4 (socket)                                   7
  5 (socket)                                   7
  6 (socket)                                   7
  7 (socket)                                   7
  8 (socket)                                   7
  9 (socket)                                   7
 10 (socket)                                   7
 11 logfile                                    2
 12 /doc0/Log/log.txt                          3
 13 /doc0/CONFIG_A/System                      3
 14 /doc0/CONFIG_A/Entity                      3
 15 /doc0/CONFIG_A/Network                     3
 16 /doc0/SW_B/fpga.rbf                        3
 17 (socket)                                   7
 18 (socket)                                   7
 19 /tyCo/1                                    1
 20 (socket)                                   7
 21 (socket)                                   7
 22 (socket)                                   7
 23 (socket)                                   7
 24 (socket)                                   7
 25 (socket)                                   7
 26 stdio_pty_16bd7d8.M                        6
 27 (socket)                                   7
 28 (socket)                                   7
 29 stdio_pty_16bd7d8.S                        5
value = 100 = 0x64 = 'd'
```

What is the regular expression that will catch the index of the last line in the table in both cases ?

Comment: what have you already tried?

Comment: I am new to the regular expressions so I have only managed to catch the whole table. And then I wondered if I can grout it and apply another regular expression in order to catch the index of the last row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
\d+(?=\D*?value = 100 = 0x64 = 'd')
```

**[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aPHrWl/1)**

**Explanation:**

- `\d+` - matches 1+ occurrences of a digit
- `(?=\D*?value = 100 = 0x64 = 'd')` - positive lookahead to make sure that the current position is followed by 0+ occurrences of non-digits, as few as possible, followed by the string `value = 100 = 0x64 = 'd'`

Comment: By the way, how would I make sure that the index that I catch is the first in the line ? What if other lines would come between the index and "value = 100 = 0x64 = 'd' " ? By the way, the first character in the line is ' ' (space)

Comment: As long as those other lines do not contain a digit, [this will work](https://regex101.com/r/aPHrWl/3)

Comment: I want to protect my trap from a "<1234> " that can show up in between the table lines. I tried to use the following regex "\s\d{1,2}(?=\D*?value = 100 = 0x64 = 'd') " and I don't know why it doesn't do the work ?

Comment: Can you share the link?

Comment: The link which you shared works. What is the error you are getting? Time-out?

Comment: I don't get an error. I simply don't catch the index at the first occurence in case that I have a "<1234>" showing up between the index and "value = 100 = 0x64 = 'd' "

Comment: It will only get more complex. Like [THIS](https://regex101.com/r/wlDRu7/2)

Comment: Thanks for all the help. I found out that in a specific case, that I didn't take into account, where there is a digit at the last line and it is not the index the regular expression doesn't fit.  I have tried to check all the possible modifications do this regular expression but none did the job. Do you think that it is a good idea to use the regex or should i try other methods [link]regex101.com/r/wlDRu7/1

Comment: By the way, the complex regular expression also misses the index